# kdesvn context menu

Tags: kubuntu, svn

For some reason I no longer have the kdesvn context menu.  I'm pretty sure I did for a while.  I used to have it in both Konqueror, and the folder menu widget.

Running Kubuntu 12.04

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the package kdesvn installed ?

[image]

Part of the kdesvn are the kdesvn servicemenus.

Comment: Yes, I have kdesvn installed.  I reinstalled, and got it to work for a while.  But it just stopped working again.  No context menu.  I again tried complete removal and then re-installation, but it didn't fix it this time.